# Icon generator from SVG missing in Vaadin documentation

Tags: java, svg, icons, vaadin, generator

There was a generator (tool) on Vaadin doc page: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/icons#icon-set-generator that created or converted the JS file from a SVG input. The link to the tool has disappeared for a reason. Do you know something about that? Do you have a link to that tool? Thanks much.

The usage after conversion in Vaadin and java:

```
Icon close = new Icon("<js-file-name>", "<icon-id>");
```

I am looking at the current page https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/icons#icon-set-generator but the existing content does not offer a similar functionality.

Comment: Maybe a weird idea; contact the vendor: https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-icons

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has just recently being updated as in Vaadin 24.2 the 3rd party icon support has been improved, see  https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/icons#using-third-party-icons

(I know it is a bit un-orthodox to answer this kind of question in SO, as protocol here is not to have a link to website as primary content of the answer, but now it is un-avoidable.)